# Counting hexamers in fasta sequence and identify its structure (and interruptions)

Tags: fasta, python, phylogenetics, structural-variation

I have a lot of fasta files, each one with thousand of reads containing the hexameric motif "CCCTCT". The hexameric motif is highly continuous in most cases but interruptions may occur. I need to count the hexameric motif keeping the read ID and identify their structure (CCCTCT)n. These interruptions are real and do not come from Sequencing error

Example Sequence:(interruption in bold)

> ACATTTTTTTTCCACATCTGATGTGGAAAAAAAAAAAAATGAAATAGCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCT**CCT**CCCTCTCCCTCTCCCCACGGTCTCCCTCTCATGCGGAGCCAAAGCTGGACTGTACTGCT

Strategy 1: Count the CCCTCT motif

```
grep -on "CCCTCT" fasta.fa | cut -f 1 -d ":" | sort | uniq -c
```

> Output: `23 CCCTCT`

As you can see we have one interruption (`CCT`) in this sequence which the codes doesn't detect.

Strategy 2: Identify reads with the same structure and count repeats in each read

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict

dedup_records = defaultdict(list)
for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta.fa", "fasta"):
    # Use the sequence as the key and then have a list of id's as the value
    dedup_records[str(record.seq)].append(record.id)
with open("Output.fasta", 'w') as output:
    for seq, ids in sorted(dedup_records.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[1]), reverse=True):
        # Join the ids and write them out as the fasta
        output.write(">{}_counts{}\n".format(ids[0], len(ids)))
        output.write(seq + "\n")
```

Output: list ranking of reads with identical structures but does not show the structure

```
>ID/ccs_counts2
CCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCTCCCTCTCCCTCT.....
```

Can you please give me an idea of how to obtain the following output? example of a sequence of 23 hexamers with interruptions.

```
(CCCTCT)20 [INTERRUPTION] (CCCTCT)3
```

I have used expansion hunter, repeatFinder and repeatAnalysis-tool by PacBio but they were not particularly sensitive for this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've also mulled on this sort of puzzle in the past (when dealing with microsatellites) and I feel like there should be some elegant approaches that could fit.  How strict do you want the definition of a repeat region and interruption between repeats?  For example, more than one perfect tandem repeat triggers a match, and less than one repeat-length mismatch before it resumes counts as an interruption (rather than the end of the whole repeat)?  Or even simpler, just however many perfect matches with any-length interruptions between?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I have to be either flexible to detect some changes (if there is some) and strict to be able to report those sequences following the patterns. I guess I just figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write some clever code counting *k-mer*s, but this problem can easily be solved using the handy sequentially-operating feature of python's str.replace() method.

This code doesn't work if you need to look at the motif occurring on the other strand. Just the forward strand.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

mystring = "CCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCC\
TCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCT\
CCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCCTCTCCTCCCTCTCCCTCT"

motif = "CCCTCT"

# This replaces the motif with 1s
newstring = mystring.replace(motif, "1")
# results in 1111111111111111111111111111111111111CCT11
# silly, right?

# This whole block just parses that string and prints everything
#  the way that OP wanted.
done = False
space=""
accumulator = 0
while not done:
    if len(newstring) == 0:
        done = True
        break
    else:
        if newstring[0] == "1":
            accumulator += 1
        else:
            if accumulator != 0:
                print("{}({}){} ".format(space, motif, accumulator), end = "")
                accumulator = 0
            print(newstring[0], end = "")
            space = " "
    newstring = newstring[1::]

# This is our check after exiting the while loop.
#  This only fires if we stepped off cleanly at the
#  end of a motif.
if accumulator > 0:
    print("{}({}){} ".format(space, motif, accumulator), end = "")
print()
```

Prints, `(CCCTCT)37 CCT (CCCTCT)2`, matching OP's spec.

Comment: That looks good, but what if I have thousand of reads so I can use fasta/bam files as input. This looks fine when I have a read, am I right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this looks fine when I have a read", but this code can be put into a method and worked into your framework you already have.